# How to Override a Specific Brush in a UWP NuGet Package?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm developing a UWP class library that will be delivered as a NuGet package. This library includes a control called CustomControl. This control uses a brush called CustomForegroundTransparentBrush, which is defined in the library's resource dictionary (CustomResourceDictionary) as an alias for another brush (ForegroundTransparentBrush):

```
<StaticResource x:Key="CustomForegroundTransparentBrush" ResourceKey="ForegroundTransparentBrush" />
```

I want to provide a way for users of my library to override CustomForegroundTransparentBrush to change the color of the Custom control in their applications. However, I don't want them to change ForegroundTransparentBrush, because it's used in other places in the library.

I've tried defining a new brush with the key CustomForegroundTransparentBrush in the App.xaml and in the local resources of a test page where I'm using the Custom control, but it doesn't seem to affect the color of the control. This is what I did:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomForegroundTransparentBrush" Color="MyColor"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

And in the test page:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomForegroundTransparentBrush" Color="MyColor"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

But neither of these approaches seems to work. The CustomControl still uses the original color defined in the library's resource dictionary.

Is there a way to allow users to override CustomForegroundTransparentBrush without affecting ForegroundTransparentBrush?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the look up behavior of the XAML resource stops when your CustomControl is created. The system finds the target resource within the NuGet package, so it doesn't need to look further for the resources that you defined.

My suggestion is that you might still need to change the foreground property of the CustomControl explicitly

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to keep these resources defined in XAML or do I have to keep them as dependency properties behind CustomControl to set Foreground explicitly?

Comment: @SanjaySubramaniam You could create a new brush in your main app's XAML and explicitly set the foreground property in XAML.

Comment: https://github.com/sanjaymaniam/BrushOverridingPOC/blob/master/README.md

@Roy Li Please check out the README above when you find the time. It seems as though overriding is possible for custom controls (with a control template), but not for user UserControls. Let me know if you have a workaround to support this in a UserControl :)

Comment: @SanjaySubramaniam The github already mentioned about how to do that. You just need to try about that.